# How to append event listener script to dynamically created element formed from server side event data

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, addeventlistener, server-sent-events

I've looked through various similar questions but honestly I don't understand any of the answers (such as they are) in order to apply any of them to what I've written. I'd really appreciate some help as I'm extremely new to this and I'm very lost!

I'm attempting to update an existing page used by moderators for clearing created data as it comes in from users. It uses server side events to check for new items, the old version uses regular forms but the page takes too long to refresh after submitting data. I'm trying to use to set the form data in the background without the need for a refresh but I'm struggling to get the event listeners to attach to the visual elements. They are created dynamically from the event source data. Visually the output looks how I want it to, but it's not behaving as it needs to. One response to a similar-ish question said don't trust the console log, it could be working, but it definitely isn't, the process on the receiving end is a copy of the existing form handler for the old page, so I know that works.

I'm unsure if it's a syntax error or if I need a different approach, the errors I'm getting look like this - it can't find the element I want it to attach the script to:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at :1:37
at EventSource.source.onmessage (MOD.php:39)

This is what I've written on the receiving page:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var last = "";
    var lastqueue = "";
    var source = new EventSource("MOD-data.php"); 
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var mydata = event.data;
        var data = mydata.split('&&');
        var upddate = (data[0]);       
        var queuedata = (data[1]);            
        if (mydata != last) {           
            last = mydata;
            if (queuedata != lastqueue) {
                var Qdata = queuedata.split('||');
                for (let i = 0; i < Qdata.length; i++) {
                    var itmdata = Qdata[i].split('.');
                    var itmID = "Q" +(itmdata[0]);
                    var exists = document.getElementById(itmID);
                    if (exists === null) {
                        var itmclass = (itmdata[1]);
                        var itmbg = (itmdata[2]);
                        var itmwho = (itmdata[3]);
                        var itmimg = (itmdata[4]);
                        var rewbox = "<div id=\"" + itmID + "\" class=\"Qitm " + itmclass + "\" style=\"background:#" + itmbg + "\">" + itmwho + "<input type=\"image\" class=\"rew\" name=\"submit\" src=\"/web/rewards/" + itmimg + ".png\"></div>";
                        document.getElementById("Qcon").innerHTML += "" + rewbox + ""; 
                        
                        var newScript = document.createElement("script");
                        var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("document.getElementById(" + itmID + ").addEventListener(\"click\", Qclear, true);function Qclear() {\$.ajax({type: \"POST\",url: \"MOD-queue-clear.php\", data: \"timestamp=" + itmID + "\"})}");
                        newScript.append(inlineScript); 
                        document.getElementById(itmID).appendChild(newScript);                             
                    }; 
                };                    
                lastqueue = queuedata;
            };
            document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "<!--" + queuedata + "-->"; 
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Why do you create and append a new script instead of just running the wanted code directly?

Comment: HTML5 doesn't support inserting a script via inner HTML. Edit - that's not the full answer, the page contains several different functions, so in order to make the single server side event source propagate to all of them, it can't be run within one single container where it can just print out the output that's needed. Obviously if I'm missing a more obvious approach then I'd be grateful if someone could ELI5 to me really, but this is where I've gotten up to after much trial and error.

Comment: You are trying to call `addEventListener` on a freshly created text node there - that makes no sense to begin with, text nodes can not get event handlers attached to them.

Comment: As I said in my post, I have looked up this issue and found that people have found working solutions to this exact problem, unfortunately the syntax they're using is very alien to me so I'm not sure what my specific code should look like. Also the way I've written it was based off of 4 different suggested answers I found on this site as to how to get around that you can't output  a script to an an element via innerHTML in HTML5. If that's wrong then I'm surprised the answers got so many upvotes and I'd appreciate it if you/someone could explain how I should be adding the script?